# Factory reset an iPad without knowing the iCloud password?

Tags: ipad

Is there a way to reset a iPad or return it to factory settings if you don't know the iCloud password?

Comment: start at http://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

Just put the iPad in the DFU-Mode. Here's a tutorial: http://www.iclarified.com/1034/how-to-put-an-iphone-into-dfu-mode

After that you can restore your iPad in iTunes.

Comment: As I recall, this no longer works.  Notice the article was published 7 years ago, before the "require iCloud password to restore" feature was implemented.

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon i restored with icloud password protection on several times and never had any problems

Comment: When did you last successfully do this?  Anything post iOS 7 will ask for the iTunes username/password when it boots up.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5344761?start=45&tstart=0

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon did it with ios 8 last time about 2 weeks ago

Comment: Was said device previously signed in with your Apple ID?

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon of course

Comment: Then you're missing what I'm trying to say.  OP has a device which is likely in LOST mode.  If this is the case, the DFU trick won't work.  The device will require the original owners iCloud ID and Password on reboot.  Lost/stolen mode is specifically tied to the IMEI number, which is unique to each device.  Try putting your device in lost mode, then ask a friend to put it in DFU mode, restore it, then try logging in with their ID.  Tying it to the IMEI number is precisely how post-iOS 7 devices are nothing more than bricks when this happens.